# HTTPS is URL in plain text at first connection?

Tags: https

Let say I have never connected to the site example.com

If this site is https and I write https://example.com/supersecretpage
will the URL be sent in clear text since it's the first time I connect to the site and therefore the crypto keys were not yet exchanged? If not when does this take place? 
Could anyone explain the steps when I type that URL?

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow.  Perhaps the Information Security exchange site?

Answer (score 0):

The URL (address portion) is all that is not encrypted, the query parameters etc are encrypted, first time, every time. The address portion of the URL is in-the-clear every time for routing.

A negotiation occurs prior to the transfer of any information.

There is a lot of good documentation on the web from high level such as they question to low level details, check it out.